Trouble with a Fourier Transform
I'm getting some conflicting results when trying to take this integral :
\begin{equation}
\int^{L/2}_{-L/2}xe^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}(n-n')x}dx
\end{equation}
where $n$ and $n'$ are both integers.
I'm having trouble with the $n'=n$ case. If I take $n'=n$ before integrating then I'm left with just the integral of $x$, which is obviously zero. Now, if take the integral as is, without assuming $n'=n$, I get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{iL^2}{2\pi}\frac{(-1)^{n-n'}}{n-n'}
\end{equation}
And if I take $n'=n$ then I'm left with a divergence. I'm struggling to figure out which of the two results I should trust, and why it matters so much at which step of the calculation I take $n'=n$.

When you integrate, you are already making the assumption $n\neq n'$. You cannot then turn around and defy your assumption to plug in $n=n'$. Your assumptions must always be asserted before doing any operations.

It shows that in general $\lim \int \neq \int \lim$
